# git pull changes without overwriting local

Tags: git, github

I'm working on the `dev`(local) branch and I'm done editing and want to merge the `dev` branch into `master`( I have not committed any changes yet). However my collaborator has made some changes on the `master` remote branch. So how can I pull those changes on `master` and then merge my `dev` branch into it, keeping the pulled changes on `master` after merging?

Comment: Don't develop on the dev branch? Consider creating a new branch on the current commit, then reset dev to match the remote?

Comment: I order to pull changes into master you first have to check out master. If this, or the pull command, would end up modifying any of the same files you have already modified, then you can't check out master, or pull, depending on which command would modify those files. Stash your changes first, or commit.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You may not be able to "pull" changes of master without checking it out  but git fetch can be used to get the changes without checking out master.

Comment: Agreed, but he's talking about merging *into* master, which will necessitate a checkout of master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this situation. Unfortunately git does not make it easy to integrate such changes.

First you have to fetch the changes of the `master` branch. Assuming the changes in the `master` are on the remote repository "origin" the following command fetches the changes of remote `master` to your local `master` branch:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

Afterwards you can integrate the changes in your `dev` branch e.g. by rebase or merge assuming you have no uncommited local changes (otherwise use git stash/git stash pop to deal with those changes):

```
# Only necessary if you have uncommited local changes
git stash 

git rebase master

# get back the uncommited local changes
git stash pop
```

Comment: After running the the above commands, will the changes made on dev (which are not committed yet) be still there, so that I can merge the `dev` into `master`. Thanks!

Comment: @Rohit In case you have uncommited changes use the additional `git stash [pop]` commands or commit your changes before rebasing/merging the changes from master.